# Pika to RabbitMQ connection failure using Raspberry PI and Docker container

Tags: python, macos, docker, rabbitmq, pika

I'm working on a simple setup for a Raspberry PI to communicate with a server via RabbitMQ and I'm not making a connection.  Here is the setup:

1. Client: Raspberry PI (Raspbien Debian 8.0) with Python 2.7 and Pika 0.10.0
2. RabbitMQ Server: MacMini running 10.11.6 - OS X El Capitan with Docker

Docker execution on Mac:

```
docker run -v /Users/tigelane/Documents/Development/brimstone_manager:/var/lib/rabbitmq -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3
```

Python code to execute on client:

```
def rabbit_post():
    entry = get_ipaddress()
    post_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d %B %Y : %I:%M%p")
    rabbit_server = 'machine.tigelane.com'

    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('machine', 'machine')
    connectionParams = pika.ConnectionParameters(host=rabbit_server, credentials=credentials)
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(connectionParams)
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')
    try: 
        channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='hello', body='Hello World!')
        print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
    except:
        print ("Unable to post to server: {}".format(rabbit_server))

    connection.close()
```

I kept seeing this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./brimstone_post.py", line
>   75, in 
>       main()   File "./brimstone_post.py", line 71, in main
>       rabbit_post()   File "./brimstone_post.py", line 58, in rabbit_post
>       connection = pika.BlockingConnection(connectionParams)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py",
>   line 339, in **init**
>       self._process_io_for_connection_setup()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py",
>   line 374, in _process_io_for_connection_setup
>       self._open_error_result.is_ready)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py",
>   line 395, in _flush_output
>       raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed() pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed

I had read a few other posts and tried some things like the following to troubleshoot:

1. Viewing the rabbitmq logs:  `docker logs some-rabbit` The log file
   didn't show any connection.
2. Capturing traffic on the raspberry to
   see if I'm even trying to send traffic to the server:  `sudo tcpdump
   port 5672`
3. Making sure the Firewall was turned off / ports open on the Mac.

I finally realized that on the Docker container there is not `-p` option to forward ports to the container.  I changed the container to open ports 5672 on the command-line and and now it's working.  Hope this can help someone else that might be using the documents from hub.docker.com on RabbitMQ.

This is the example they give for the docker container:  `$ docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3`

This is the new command I'm using to start my RabbitMQ docker container and it's working well:  `docker run -v /Users/tigelane/Documents/Development/brimstone_manager:/var/lib/rabbitmq -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3`

While I think I have solved my problem, I have this nagging feeling that I'm missing something (besides other ports that I might need to add) and that there may have been a reason that the port was omitted on the example, or maybe they just left it off thinking everyone would add the port naturally because that's how you use Docker containers.  Either way, please feel free to correct my mistake.